# How to enter values, save them to a new file and search for the values in the file

Tags: ruby, search

I have a school assignment that I need help with. 
This is the description of the assignment:

Ruby program that can hold these values:

- Artifacts
- Values
- Assumptions

It shall be possible for a user:

- To enter these three types of values.
- Search for a value of type Artifacts, Values or Assumptions.
- The program shall use loops and at least one class definition.

The only function that won't work out for me are these lines:

```
f= File.new("Artefacts", "r") 
puts "Search for information regarding cultural information"
userinput = gets.chomp
if File.readlines("Artefacts").include?('userinput')
  puts "We have found your input."
else 
  puts "We have not found your input."
f.close
```

No matter what the user inserts, it only displays "We have not found your input".

Comment: Try debugging this yourself.  Run the one-line program `p File.readlines("Artefacts")` and see what it prints.  Also insert the line `p userinput` into your program in an appropriate place to see what the user input string looks like.

Comment: this would be a good time to try a debugger like `byebug` - you can put a breakpoint in your code and check your variables at runtime.

Comment: I'd recommend reading “[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)”. It'll help future questions. I'd also recommend reading "[mcve]". Homework questions are a touchy subject on SO. I'd highly recommend putting more effort into your question, and into debugging it. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”

Answer (score 0):

Part A: get user input and write to file

```
  def write_to_file(path, string)
    # 'a' means append
    # it will create the file if it doesnt exist
    File.open(path, 'a') do |file|
      file.write string + "\n"
    end
  end

  path = "Artefacts"
  num_inputs = 3
  num_inputs.times do |i|
    puts "enter input (#{i + 1} / #{num_inputs}):"
    write_to_file path, gets.chomp
  end

  puts `cat #{path}`
  # if you entered "foo" for each input,
  # this will show:
  # foo
  # foo
  # foo
```

Part B: read a file and check if it contains a string:

```
  path = "./Artefacts"
  query = "foo"

  text = File.read path
  # this will be a string with all the text

  lines = File.readlines path
  # this will be an array of strings (one for each line)

  is_text_found = text.include? query
  # or 
  is_text_found = lines.any? do |line|
    line.include? query
  end
```